# Unable to import .p12 keystore

Tags: java, ssl, keytool, private-key, jks

I created a .p12 keystore using openssl from a pkcs8 keystore. Now I'm trying to import the private key using java Keytool into a new JKS keystore. I tried the command:

> keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore newKS.p12 -srcstoretype pkcs12
>   -srcstorepass pass -destkeystore exportedJks.jks -deststoretype jks -deststorepass pass

But I get the following error message:

> keytool error: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Get Key
>   failed: EC KeyFactory not available

How can I resolve this error so I can import this key into a new JKS keystore?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281257/why-was-this-question-put-on-hold-as-too-broad

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The error message means that the Java runtime could not find a crypto provider for ECC (elliptic curve cryptography) algorithms.

Java 6 contains only basic support for ECC: It knows the OIDs of most EC algorithms and therefore knows that it must find an "EC KeyFactory". However, by default no provider is installed that can handle these algorithms.

The [SunEC provider](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html#SunEC) with full ECC support was added in Java 7, so the easiest solution for this problem is to use keytool from a Java 7 or 8 runtime.